# Stamina for running long

Tags: running

Although I am not obese I tend to get very exhausted after 2-3 minutes of running (max). So how can I increase the stamina for running.

Although I take healthy diet but still get exhausted easily. I have no heart condition either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to build it up gradually, and not start too fast.

Start by running from one lamp post to the next. Then walking the next one.  When you can manage that ok, run 2 lamp posts and walk one.

Try to start at a pace that feels easy, that you can maintain for the distance.

There is an app you can get for iPhones called couch to 5k which is very good.  A run/walk program.

Start slowly, with a run walk program and I'm sure you will see progress fairly quickly.

Good luck on your journey

Comment: I'm not sure there will be a better answer.  There is no 'quick and easy' method to this, you just have to put the miles in.  However, once you have gotten to the point where you can run for 2-3 hours and desire to run longer but find yourself zapped for energy you should look into fueling.  But, you're a little ways away from that at this point :)

Comment: Amen for using a tried and tested program like Couch To 5k. I've seen plenty of people picking up running after following that program

Comment: Couch to 5k and the Galloway run/walk programs are going to be your best bet. Excellent recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about pacing yourself. To improve your stamina, start your run at a pace that feels extremely easy to maintain. As the minutes pass, your perceived effort will go up. Gradually increase your run time, while gradually decreasing the time of your walk breaks. Once you hit 30 minutes of continuous running, you can start some short interval work. Run shorter segments at faster, uncomfortable pace. Take walking breaks in between each interval. These faster segments will improve your overall cardiovascular fitness and make your normal pace feel easier, thereby increasing both your endurance and speed.  Good luck!